# Unable to echo decoded JSON from file_get_contents('php://input') for an Aws sns POST data

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I made a php file and registered its endpoint as a subscriber to a SNS topic. When I publish a new message to the topic, I do get an email with the right message using the following code but I am not able to echo/print the message on the browser.

```
$msg_body ='';
$msg =  json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$msg_body = $msg["Message"];
echo $msg_body;
mail('xyz@gmail.com','From PHP', $msg_body);
```

Suggestions ?

Comment: what is your enctype? php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".

Comment: Its application/json.